# PHP unlink() не работает на сервере

Tags: php, iis

Здравствуйте,есть задача в определённом участке кода реализовать удаление файлика xml  из директории,где находится index.php.Проблема в том, что скрипт unlink($xml.".xml"); на Denver,openserver срабатывает,а на боевом серваке Win Server 2012r с с IIS не хочет,файлик не удаляется,все перепробывал,что делать?

Comment: если нет прав, то не удалите. Проверьте логи и посмотрите, что возвращает функция `unlink`

Comment: права нужны `IUSR`, но давать права на запись в папку где скрипты лежат - не хорошо. логично было бы переместить файл в другую директорию, куда доступ уже и предоставить.

Comment: А эти настройки по правам доступа где-то в  Диспетчере IIS смотреть,просто в Windows Server опыта администрирования нету?